# Flutter post request to login iColud.com/find

Tags: flutter

Hello guys i wanted to login in icloud.com/find server but below code return 302 status code. How can i login anyone help?

```
  Future _findMyLogin() async {
// SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
String url = "https://idmsa.apple.com/appleauth/auth/signin";
var jsonresponse;
var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url),
    body: ({
      "email": "user@gmail.com",
      "password": "userpass",
    }));
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  jsonresponse = jsonDecode(response.body);
  print(jsonresponse);
  print("Sucess");
  // sharedPreferences.setString("trustTokens", jsonresponse["trustTokens"]);
} else {
  // jsonresponse = jsonDecode(response.body);
  // print(jsonresponse["trustTokens"][0]["0"]);
  print(response.statusCode);
}
```

}

Comment: are there any headers?

Comment: this is first time doing post request i dont know what header is

Answer (score 0):

```
var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url),
    body: jsonEncode(<String,String>{
      "email": "user@gmail.com",
      "password": "userpass",
    }));
```

You forget to use jsonEncode.
but first, check in your response to whether it has **headers** or not.

Comment: How can i do that. i have tried to login to icloud.com/find then inspect the network and it also have token. can you go and check it out and help me to implement with full steps?

Comment: you must look in this website to learn post API [Flutter official docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/send-data)
or learn from video[youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QsT1pltLLX8&ab_channel=EasyApproach)